Gemini Api Android: SerializationException when deserializing response from server
I am using the Gemini Api for text prompt calls; it works pretty fine earlier, but today I am getting a SerializationException whenever I make Api request. I already trying updating gemini dependency, Play Services, and test on different phones and emulators, but it has not solved
Here is Exception message:
    com.google.ai.client.generativeai.type.SerializationException: Something went wrong while trying to deserialize a response from the server.
17:07:47.015  E     at com.google.ai.client.generativeai.type.GoogleGenerativeAIException$Companion.from(Exceptions.kt:41)
17:07:47.015  E     at com.google.ai.client.generativeai.GenerativeModel.generateContent(GenerativeModel.kt:116)
17:07:47.015  E     at com.google.ai.client.generativeai.GenerativeModel$generateContent$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:15)
17:07:47.015  E     at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
17:07:47.015  E     at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
17:07:47.015  E     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
17:07:47.015  E     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
17:07:47.015  E     at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
17:07:47.015  E     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
17:07:47.015  E     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8762)
17:07:47.015  E     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
17:07:47.015  E     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:604)
17:07:47.015  E     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
17:07:47.016  E  Caused by: io.ktor.serialization.JsonConvertException: Illegal input: Field 'totalTokenCount' is required for type with serial name 'com.google.ai.client.generativeai.common.UsageMetadata', but it was missing at path: $.usageMetadata
17:07:47.016  E     at io.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.KotlinxSerializationConverter.deserialize(KotlinxSerializationConverter.kt:90)
17:07:47.016  E     at io.ktor.serialization.ContentConverterKt$deserialize$$inlined$map$1$2.emit(Emitters.kt:224)
17:07:47.016  E     at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__BuildersKt$asFlow$$inlined$unsafeFlow$3.collect(SafeCollector.common.kt:116)
17:07:47.016  E     at io.ktor.serialization.ContentConverterKt$deserialize$$inlined$map$1.collect(SafeCollector.common.kt:113)
17:07:47.016  E     at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ReduceKt.firstOrNull(Reduce.kt:243)
17:07:47.016  E     at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt.firstOrNull(Unknown Source:1)
17:07:47.016  E     at io.ktor.serialization.ContentConverterKt.deserialize(ContentConverter.kt:123)
17:07:47.016  E     at io.ktor.client.plugins.contentnegotiation.ContentNegotiation.convertResponse$ktor_client_content_negotiation(ContentNegotiation.kt:230)
17:07:47.016  E     at io.ktor.client.plugins.contentnegotiation.ContentNegotiation$Plugin$install$2.invokeSuspend(ContentNegotiation.kt:262)
17:07:47.016  E     at io.ktor.client.plugins.contentnegotiation.ContentNegotiation$Plugin$install$2.invoke(Unknown Source:13)
17:07:47.016  E     at io.ktor.client.plugins.contentnegotiation.ContentNegotiation$Plugin$install$2.invoke(Unknown Source:6)
17:07:47.016  E     at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:120)
17:07:47.016  E     at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:78)
17:07:47.016  E     at io.ktor.client.HttpClient$4.invokeSuspend(HttpClient.kt:177)
17:07:47.016  E     at io.ktor.client.HttpClient$4.invoke(Unknown Source:11)
17:07:47.016  E     at io.ktor.client.HttpClient$4.invoke(Unknown Source:6)
17:07:47.016  E     at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:120)
17:07:47.016  E     at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:78)
17:07:47.016  E     at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceedWith(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:88)
17:07:47.016  E     at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpCallValidator$Companion$install$2.invokeSuspend(HttpCallValidator.kt:142)
17:07:47.016  E     at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpCallValidator$Companion$install$2.invoke(Unknown Source:13)
17:07:47.016  E     at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpCallValidator$Companion$install$2.invoke(Unknown Source:6)
17:07:47.016  E     at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:120)
17:07:47.016  E     at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:78)
17:07:47.016  E     at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.execute$ktor_utils(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:98)
17:07:47.016  E     at io.ktor.util.pipeline.Pipeline.execute(Pipeline.kt:77)
17:07:47.016  E     at io.ktor.client.call.HttpClientCall.bodyNullable(HttpClientCall.kt:88)
17:07:47.016  E     at com.google.ai.client.generativeai.common.APIController.generateContent(APIController.kt:262)
17:07:47.016  E     at com.google.ai.client.generativeai.common.APIController$generateContent$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:15)
17:07:47.016  E     at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
17:07:47.016  E     at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
17:07:47.016  E     ... 8 more
17:07:47.016  E  Caused by: kotlinx.serialization.MissingFieldException: Field 'totalTokenCount' is required for type with serial name 'com.google.ai.client.generativeai.common.UsageMetadata', but it was missing at path: $.usageMetadata
17:07:47.016  E     at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.StreamingJsonDecoder.decodeSerializableValue(StreamingJsonDecoder.kt:93)
17:07:47.016  E     at kotlinx.serialization.encoding.AbstractDecoder.decodeSerializableValue(AbstractDecoder.kt:43)
17:07:47.016  E     at kotlinx.serialization.encoding.AbstractDecoder.decodeNullableSerializableElement(AbstractDecoder.kt:79)
17:07:47.016  E     at com.google.ai.client.generativeai.common.GenerateContentResponse$$serializer.deserialize(Response.kt:26)
17:07:47.017  E     at com.google.ai.client.generativeai.common.GenerateContentResponse$$serializer.deserialize(Response.kt:26)
17:07:47.017  E     at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.StreamingJsonDecoder.decodeSerializableValue(StreamingJsonDecoder.kt:70)
17:07:47.017  E     at kotlinx.serialization.json.Json.decodeFromString(Json.kt:107)
17:07:47.017  E     at io.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.KotlinxSerializationConverter.deserialize(KotlinxSerializationConverter.kt:82)
17:07:47.017  E     ... 38 more
17:07:47.017  E  Caused by: kotlinx.serialization.MissingFieldException: Field 'totalTokenCount' is required for type with serial name 'com.google.ai.client.generativeai.common.UsageMetadata', but it was missing
17:07:47.017  E     at kotlinx.serialization.internal.PluginExceptionsKt.throwMissingFieldException(PluginExceptions.kt:20)
17:07:47.017  E     at com.google.ai.client.generativeai.common.UsageMetadata.<init>(Response.kt:39)
17:07:47.017  E     at com.google.ai.client.generativeai.common.UsageMetadata$$serializer.deserialize(Response.kt:39)
17:07:47.017  E     at com.google.ai.client.generativeai.common.UsageMetadata$$serializer.deserialize(Response.kt:39)
17:07:47.017  E     at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.StreamingJsonDecoder.decodeSerializableValue(StreamingJsonDecoder.kt:70)
17:07:47.017  E     ... 45 more

My Code is:
String prompt = Constants.getDetailsPrompt(title);
        GenerativeModel generativeModel = new GenerativeModel("gemini-pro", "--");
        GenerativeModelFutures generativeModelFutures = GenerativeModelFutures.from(generativeModel);
        Content content = new Content.Builder()
                .addText(prompt)
                .build();

        Executor executor = Runnable::run;
        ListenableFuture<GenerateContentResponse> response = generativeModelFutures.generateContent(content);
        Futures.addCallback(response, new FutureCallback<GenerateContentResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(GenerateContentResponse result) {
                String resultText = result.getText();
                resultText = resultText.replace("*", "");
                Timber.d("Result: %s", resultText);
                binding.tvDetails.setText(resultText);
                binding.tvDetails.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                binding.svResult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                binding.loadingAnimation.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Throwable t) {
                Timber.e(t);
            }
        }, executor);


where in your code is the error coming from it says your trying to read totalTokenCount but i dont see that in your code.

Gemini throws an exception, which I print in the failure section of my code.

I already included it. Here is failure part of code that catches exceptions
@Override
public void onFailure(@NonNull Throwable t) {
Timber.e(t);
}

Its a bug in the API.

This appears to be a bug in the API it was reported first over on the GO lib.
proto: (line 34:3): unknown field "usageMetadata"

Yeah, found same issue in android
https://github.com/google-gemini/generative-ai-android/issues/134

The api just started populating that fiend yesterday they are going to try to get it fixed asap.

This was a transient issue with the data returned by the service and how the Android SDK interpreted it. It's fixed now.
Also, starting with release 0.5.0 https://github.com/google-gemini/generative-ai-android/releases/tag/v0.5.0 the SDK is more resilient to this encoding error.
